# What is the right way to create a MultiSig?

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

After following https://github.com/wobine/blackboard101/blob/master/wbn_multisigs_pt2_spend-funds.py for creating a MultiSig, I end up with a Multisig address.

On Validate Address it shows as valid but isMine:false. 
I have send some test coins, still list unspend shows up as an empty array.
I validated the public addresses and all belong to the same wallet.
Txn shows up with confirmations on blockchain.info

So, my question is, is it the right way to create it? Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *addmultisigaddress nrequired ["key",...] ( "account" )* JSON-RPC command in order to create a p2sh address that will be considered your own.

Comment: Thanks Alcio, I think your answer, answers this specific question, I will mark it as the answer as soon as I am able to test it out.